# Cognito IdentityId in Lambda Function through API Gateway

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'd like to get cognito identity id in lambda function.(python2.7)

I call api from ios app authenticated by cognito.
I tried this code. But it does not work.

```
id = context.identity.cognito_identity_id # return null
```

Do you have any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cognito identity ID is available in the API Gateway context which is different from the Lambda context. You must sent the API Gateway context to your Lambda function via a mapping template.

i.e.
{
"cognitoIdentityId" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId"
}

then in Lambda you can use event.cognitoIdentityId

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Answer (score 2):

Note that this will not work if you do not invoke with caller credentials - therefore this is impossible to do without re-writing 90% of the Amazon encryption libraries manually if you want to integrate with your user pools.

This entire library is a mess - if you happen to be new to the library and thinking about using it I have to strongly suggest you stay away - it's been an absolute nightmare for us!

At the moment our last resort is going to be to manually set an custom attribute on the user and use the admin SDK to get it on every request which is pretty annoying but does get the job working.

From what I have seen, they are re-working the entire library to bring it all together which will be nice to see so make sure you implement things in a way you can update to that when they do upgrade things.